# Inital "get" done by Team Build

Tags: tfs, msbuild, build-automation, tfsbuild

Does anyone have any links to documents about the initial "get" done Team Build (when the files from the ConfigurationFolderPath (ie TFSBuild.proj) are downloaded).

All I could find was this one blog post:
http://blogs.msdn.com/jpricket/archive/2007/12/10/changing-the-recursion-type-for-the-initial-get-that-team-build-does.aspx

I would like more info about this.  (Namely can I make it point to more than one folder).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it's limited to a single folder and the only configuration you can do is the one specified in that blog post (i.e. choose between no, single level, and full recursion).